# Remove all lines that contain $PWD

Tags: text-processing, variable, pwd

I have a file that contains paths - looks like this:

```
/Users/a/Desktop
/Users/a/Documents
/Users/a/Documents/Work
```

What would be the easiest way to remove all lines that contain the current directory (`$PWD`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -v "^$PWD$" FILE-LIST
```

- `-v` inverses the search, so only non-matching lines are printed
- `^...$` ensures that the pattern only matches the whole line (otherwise all subdirectories of `$PWD` would got filtered as well)

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect - simple and works!

Comment: See also the -x option which does the ^ and $ for you

Comment: `grep -xvF -- "$PWD" ` should be safe, lest the present working directory name comprise grep regex metachars and/or options.